# typescript fails to import lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, lodash

I have a project that uses typescript and runs in node.

I have lodash in my dependencies of the package.json installed.

Originally I imported it like this:

```
import _ from "lodash";
console.log(_)
```

Originally this worked and it still works in all my other packages.
But not in this one. It compiles just fine, but it prints undefined at runtime.

The js code generated from this looks like this:

```
const lodash_1 = require("lodash");
console.log(lodash_1.default);
```

`.default` does not exist on lodash_1, so that is why it fails.

My solution is to use this ts code instead:

```
import { LoDashStatic } from "lodash";
const _: LoDashStatic = require("lodash");
console.log(_);
```

this compiles to:

```
const _ = require("lodash");
console.log(_);
```

No `.default`, it works fine.

Why does this happen?

Comment: You can import `lodash` like `import * as _ from 'lodash'`

Comment: Just as a reminder: it's late 2020, plain JS has a _ton_ of stuff built in these days that, years ago, we needed jquery and lodash for. Good idea to check whether you even _need_ lodash if you're starting a new project, because you almost certainly won't anymore.

Comment: the start import also works and is shorter, that is nice. 
VS Code seems not to like it, it suggests to convert it to a "default import", which yields the broken form with the star.

Comment: Set `--esModuleInterop`